# Nuxt.js3 plugin's context becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, supabase, nuxtjs3

I am developing an application using Nuxt.js3 and supabase.

Nuxt.js in plugins/supabase.server.js (I haven't figured out if server or client is better for this too.) I want to use "supabase = createClient(~~)" from index.vue.

However, I get undefined, either because the import is not working or because I am calling it the wrong way.

If I use the mustache syntax and call it like "{{ $supabase }}", the function will appear.

(I am not good at English, so I use translated sentences.)

***plugins/supabase.server.js***

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();
  nuxtApp.provide('supabase', () => createClient(config.supabaseUrl, config.supabaseKey))
})
declare module '#app' {
  interface NuxtApp {
    $supabase (): string
  }
}
```

***pages/index.vue***

```
<script setup>
console.log($supabase) //$supabase is not defined
</script>
<template>
{{ $supabase }} // () => createClient(config.supabaseUrl, config.supabaseKey)

</template>
```

Comment: Where exactly is this console.log? You're referring it as global variable. It's not. You need to access instance property. This is what `{{ $supabase }}` does

Comment: @EstusFlask
Thanks for the reply. I forgot to write it, so I added it.
I wrote console.log($supabase) in <script setup>.

Comment: I'm not sure this works good with `script setup` as it's very limiting. This is specific to Nuxt but I'd expect it to be available in regular `script`'s `context`

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you, I hope there is a way to implement this in script setup, but if not, I'll give up. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Please import `useRuntimeConfig` from `'#app'`. So in your example change the first line:

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
```

Into:

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin, useRuntimeConfig } from '#app'
```